# Need less parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, partition, bigdata

I am doing the following process

```
rdd.toDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("Some Column").parquet(output_path)
```

However, under each partition, there are too many parquet files and each of them, the size is very small, that will makes my following steps become very slow to load all the parquet files. Is there a better way that under each partition, make less parquet files and increase the single parquet file size?

Comment: Please go through for detailed solution to the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840837/how-to-efficiently-read-multiple-small-parquet-files-with-spark-is-there-a-comb

Answer (score 3):

You can repartition before save:

```
rdd.toDF.repartition("Some Column").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("Some Column")
```

Comment: That will work I believe. However, repartition() cause lots of network traffic. I am wondering if there is any other efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this problem.

Actually you can't control the partition of files because it depends on the executor doing.

The way to work around it is using method `coalesce` to make a shuffle and you can make how many partition you want but it's not efficient way you also need to set driver memory enough to handle this operation.

```
df = df.coalesce(numPartitions).write.partitionBy(""yyyyy").parquet("xxxx")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I replace "coalesce" with another partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions)), trying if that can be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue. The problem is if you use coalesce each partition gets same number of parquet files. Now different partitions have different size so ideally I need different coalesce for each partition.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be really quite expensive if you open a lot of small files. Let's say you open 1k files and each filesize are far from the value of your **parquet.block.size**.

Here are my suggestions:

- Create a job that will first merge your input parquet files to have smaller number of files where their sizes are near or equal to **parquet.block.size**. The default block size for 128Mb, though it's configurable by updating **parquet.block.size**. Spark would love if your parquet file is near before or equal the value of your **parquet.block.size**. The block size is the size of a row group being buffered in memory.
- Or update your spark job to just read limited number of files
- Or if you have a big machine and/or resources, just do the right tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Hive query has a way to merge small files into larger one. This is not available in spark sql. Also, reducing spark.sql.shuffle.partitions wont help with Dataframe API. 
I tried below solution and it generated lesser number of parquet files(from 800 parquet files to 29).

Suppose the data is loaded to a dataframe df

1. Create a temporary table in hive.

   ```
   df.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")
   spark.sql("CREATE TABLE test_temp LIKE test")
   spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE test_temp SELECT * FROM tempTable")
   ```

   The test_temp will contain small parquet files.
2. Populate final hive table from temporary table

   ```
   spark.sql("INSERT INTO test SELECT * FROM test_temp")
   ```

The final table will contain lesser files. Drop temporary table after populating final table.